# how to save video opencv-python on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VidwoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == cv2.flip(frame,0):

        # Write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break;

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows ()
```

I want to save video using opencv-python. after this code runs, I indeed get the 'output.avi' file, but i cannot open it. 
the environment i am working on is Mac10.10, opencv2.4.11, python2.7,
anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: Try `-1` as your FOURCC, that way you can select which codec to use.

Comment: Sorry, I doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This is my code after set the **correct size** for **VideoWriter** I can get my video.

```py
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
width = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) + 0.5)
height = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) + 0.5)
size = (width, height)

fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, size)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # frame = cv.flip(frame, 0)
    # write the flipped frame
    out.write(frame)
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code will not run because you are comparing `ret` of type Bool to the output of the `cv2.flip` function, which is an output array (your flipped frame). You should change you code to:

```
...
if ret == True:
    fliped = cv2.flip(frame,0)
    out.write(fliped)
    ...
```

Comment: @TylerXie are you sure that your VideoCapture device was successfully opened? Probably you never go inside the while loop. You can try to open a  video file like: ` cv2.VideoCapture('somefile.mp4')`.